# Hypothesis testing from negative binomial data

Tags: probability, statistics

For each trial I flip a coin until $3$ heads or $3$ tails occur, whichever comes first. Out of $10$ trials, $3$ trials result in $3$ flips, $3$ trials result in 4 flips, and $4$ trials result in $5$ flips. How can I use this data to test whether the coin is a fair coin?

Comment: There is a straightforward conjugate Bayesian analysis to do so. Using the Jeffreys prior it also provides a frequentist solution.